# Infinite loop when accessing a page

Tags: cakephp, loops, memory, cakephp-1.2, infinite

---

I have this cakePHP app (version 1.2) which started to behave oddly producing internal server errors when loading a certain page.

I then installed xDebug on my local Mamp environment and found out that the app runs into a loop when this page is accessed. Unfortunately I don't know how to interpret this, maybe you can help me out and point me into a direction (before I start publishing code here).

Many thanks!

[pic: infinite loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8OBY.png)

EDIT
- line 14 in the pic refers to the file mmenu.ctp which contains following request:

```
$menus = $this->requestAction('/menus/reto');
```

The MenusController then contains following action:

class

```
 MenusController extends AppController {
            var $name = 'Menus';
            var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
            function reto(){
                $this->Menu->recursive = 2;
                return $this->Menu->find('all', array('conditions' => array("parent_id" => 0), 'order' => 'Menu.order asc'));
            }
     ...
    }
```

I hope that helps.

EDIT 2:
Okey, I did more testing. In that page that is getting loaded, there are 3 requestActions:
The 1. one loads a Navigation from the database.
The 2. and the 3. calls a GalleryController. At both times the same controller function but with different arguments.

Now when I either get rid of the 1. or the two gallery requests, the site loads without any problems.

Might it be, that requestAction uses up too much memory? 
But, why cakephp starts an infinite loop is still weird to me.

The net tab of firebug did not reveal any usable info. It just stated the request to that particular site that I try to load.

EDIT 3:

Thanks for your reply Nunser! 
I did add the menu function in the app_controler file within a beforeRender function:

```
$this->loadModel('Menu');

            if (!isset($this->viewVars['mainMenu'])) 
            {
              $this->set(
                    'mainMenu', $this->Menu->find('all', 
                        array('conditions' => array("parent_id" => 0), 'recursive' => '2', 'order' => 'Menu.order asc')
                        )
                    );

            }
```

I did not get rid of the recursive=2 though, because i need joins from the menu table to a content table where additional infos are saved, like the url for example... the results array must look like this:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Menu] => Array
                (
                    ...

                )
            [Content] => Array
                (

                    [url] => urlhere
                  ...

                )
                [Child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Content] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => url here...
                                )

                        )

                   ...
                )

        )
```

Not sure how i can get this with recursive=-1. Looked into [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Behaviors/Containable.html) but with no luck.

Anyway, much more interesting is the 2. and the 3. requestAction to the GalleriesController:
Even if I have a very basic controller, only returning a string, when calling

```
echo $this->requestAction('/galleries/sidegal');

<?php
    class GalleriesController extends AppController {
        var $name = 'Galleries';
        var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

        function sidegal() {
        return 'testString';
        }
            }
?>
```

I get a loop. Any ideas on this?

EDIT 4:
Soooo, after a hell of a lot of time I started up trying things with my GalleryModel, which looked like this first:

```
var $hasMany = array(
        'Gimage' => array(
            'className' => 'Gimage',
            'foreignKey' => 'gallery_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => 'Gimage.order asc',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => '' ),
            'Child' => array('className' => 'Gallery',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
            'order' => 'Child.order asc'
            ),
            );
```

I spoted then, that the 'Child' array causes problems. So I changed the word Child to Children it suddenly worked.
The SOLUTION was the following:

```
var $hasMany = array(
            'Gimage' => array(
                'className' => 'Gimage',
                'foreignKey' => 'gallery_id',
                'dependent' => true,
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => 'Gimage.order asc',
                'limit' => '',
                'offset' => '',
                'exclusive' => '',
                'finderQuery' => '',
                'counterQuery' => '' ),
                'Children' => array('className' => 'Gallery',
                'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
                'order' => 'Children.order asc'
                ),
                );
```

I am happy that it works now.
Thanks for your support Nunser, much appreaciated.

Comment: Are you doing a requestAction inside the view (line 14 of the pic) causing the problem? if so can you post the respective action code?

Comment: Use Firebug's "Net" tab to see all the redirects. The urls should give you some hints as to what to search for in your code.

Comment: Yes Nunser, there is such a request in the mmenu.ctp. ill be updating my code above in a second and I will look into Firbug's Net tab. Thanks guys

Comment: Please post and answer with your solution and accept it, so other pleople trying to help know this is solved :)

Comment: How do I do this? I cant press "Answer your Question" at the bottom of this page :)

Comment: Why can't you? An alert is going to show up, but just press ok and add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Uff, recursion alert there.

So, you have a Menu that has submenus, and you're trying to get the menus where `parent_id = 0`, but with `$recursive = 2`, you're getting

```
Menu where parent_id = 0
    Submenus of this menu where parent_id = menu_id
        Parent menu of this submenu where parent_id = 0
            ...forever and ever
```

See the recursion there? That happens because you set recursion to 2. See the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#recursive). Your getting a lot of info you don't even need. As general rule, try to have the recursion set to -1 and retrieve the data with [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Behaviors/Containable.html), believe me, even if the queries may be a little more hassle to make, the data you're retrieving will be considerably less depending on your associations. I've run into memory problems with cake before using containable and recursion correctly.

Well, anyway, to the point.
If in `reto()` you *only* want the menus with `parent_id = 0`, then do

```
$this->Menu->recursive = -1;
return $this->Menu->find('all', array('conditions' => array("parent_id" => 0), 'order' => 'Menu.order asc'));
```

and the loop will desapear.

If you want menus and *first tear* submenu, try

```
 $this->Menu->recursive = -1;
 return $this->Menu->find('all', array('conditions' => array("parent_id" => 0),
                                       'recursive' => -1, //just to be sure
                                       'contain' => 'Menu',
                                       'order' => 'Menu.order asc'));
```

or something like that (I haven't work with 1.2, so the syntax may be a bit different).

Oh, and as a side note regarding your last edit: requestAction makes a lot of delay, and is frown upon within the MVC frameworks. Try removing it. I don't think that *that* is causing the loop problem, but do look into options. If your using it for navigation, why not add the same menu function seen here in the beforeRender of the AppController, set the array into a view variable, and just display it, instead of doing a requestAction every time?